# Eliminar hover de una etiqueta td especifica, sin afectar a las demás etiquetas td de una fila

Tags: html, css

Necesito que una etiqueta `td` no cambie de color junto con todos las demás etiquetas `td`, es decir, que el área marcada con rojo se muestre transparente cuando paso el mouse sobre toda la fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que estoy utilizando pero solo se ejecuta cuando paso solo el área roja, mas no cuando lo paso sobre otra columna de la misma fila.

```
td.state:hover{
  background-color: transparent !important;
 }
```

Este es la etiqueta `td` que quiero dejar con color transparente

```
 <td class='state'></td>
 <td class='warning'>Objeto social </td>
 <td colspan='10'>$arreglo[11]</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es primero que todo agregar una clase a ese `<tr>` que es realmente el que va a ejecutar el `hover` y cambiar tu selector:

```
<tr class="fila">
    <td class='state'></td>
    <td class='warning'>Objeto social </td>
    <td colspan='10'>$arreglo[11]</td>
</tr>
```

Y en tu **CSS**

```
tr.fila:hover td.state{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

De esta forma se aplicará la transparencia a tu `<td>` cuando estén encima de cualquier columna perteneciente al `<tr>`

Ejemplo funcional:

```css
tr.fila:hover td{
    background-color: #ccc;
}

tr.fila:hover td.state{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="5">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="fila">
            <td class='state'>Estado</td>
            <td class='warning'>Objeto social </td>
            <td colspan='10'>dato</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, lo que hice fue cambiar `transparent` por el color de fondo quedando

`tr.info:hover td.state{
border-left: 1px solid transparent;
background-color: #8f8f8c !important;
}`

Pero si es necesario poner el `tr` gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: @AgusOlivera así es ya solo es que cambies los colores que de verdad necesitas, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Es por que solo le estas aplicando ese estilo al `td` que tiene la clase `state`, si lo cambias y solo dejas

```
td:hover {
   background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

te va poner transparente todos los `td` de la tabla.

Comment: Quiero que cambie de color toda la fila a excepción de la primer columna, que es la que está con el cuadro rojo. Por eso le puse la clase, pero solo funciona si le paso el mouse a esa columna, pero si lo paso en cualquier otra columna de la misma fila no lo hace.

Answer (score 0):

si defines el `hover` transparente para los `td` que tengan la clase `state`, solo ellos obtendrán ese `hover`,  en el caso de `<td class='warning'>Objeto social </td>`, no posee la clase state, no tiene porque ocurrir los mismo con el. revisa eso,si pones

```
 td:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
 }
```

todos los `td` de la tabla obtendrán los estilos establecidos por el `hover`. 
Si deseas solo algunos, le agregas la clase `state`, si no todos, puedes utilizar el código anterior